# Combining multiple Rows into one Row one Column Python

Tags: python, group-by

I need to combine all the rows for a dataframe into one row in one column. For example:

```
data = ('Hello', 'are you having','', 
        'a nice day today? I am very', 
        'delighted to have snail as','',
        'my','','entree for dinner tonight.')

data = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
```

Returns:

```
print(data)
                             0
0                        Hello
1               are you having
2                             
3  a nice day today? I am very
4     delighted to have snail as
5                             
6                           my
7                             
8   entree for dinner tonight.
```

Now I'll try to combine all rows into one column:

```
data = data.rename(columns={0: 'value'})
data = data.groupby('value').apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

This will create an additional column with the string "value" for every row. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you've wanted.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = ('Hello', 'are you having','', 
        'a nice day today? I am very', 
        'delighted to have snail as','',
        'my','','entree for dinner tonight.')

data = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
data = data.rename(columns={0: 'value'})
data['new'] = data['value'].str.cat(sep=' ')#concatenate all the strings in existing column and create a new one.
print(data)
```

Output:

```
                                                 new  
0  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
1  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
2  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
3  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
4  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
5  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
6  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
7  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...  
8  Hello are you having  a nice day today? I am v...
```

Comment: thanks for the help. In the last nested statement, is there a way where I can keep only the first row and remove all additional rows as they all have the same information in them?

Comment: You'll lose all the corresponding info if there are multiple columns. Are you sure, this is the only column you have in your dataframe? If so, why go through trouble of forming a df with pandas? A simple ```" ".join(data)``` could give you your answer.